# How to generate a Graphical summary of a table using R

Tags: r

How to generate a Graphical summary as shown below on a  rectangular bar using a range of positions as a input. This is helpful for generating schematic representations. Using R or in any language.

I tried searching internet for any solution but I found none.

UPDATE:
Please let me know the name of the `libraries or hints` which can do this.
Thanks in advance.

INPUT:(Not shown Completely)

```
Helix   56 – 59         
Helix   62 – 78         
Helix   80 – 89         
Helix   95 – 102
//
Beta strand 175 – 178           
Beta strand 184 – 186       
Helix       188 – 190           
Beta strand 194 – 198       
Turn        199 – 202
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: @Henrik I don't need the complete code for solving the above problem. Please let me know the name of the libraries or hints which can do this. I will update the question accordingly. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

A -maybe not so elegant- way is the following:

```
#random data
DF <- data.frame(range = c("10 - 20", "28 - 30", "3 - 8", 
                          "100 - 180", "185 - 190", "200 - 350"), 
                    type = rep(c("helix", "beta", "turn"), 2), stringsAsFactors = F)

#manipulate "from - to" numerically
newDF <- cbind(DF, do.call(rbind, strsplit(DF$range, " - ")), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(newDF) <- c(names(DF), "xleft", "xright") #name the columns
newDF$"xleft" <- as.numeric(newDF$"xleft")  #make the values numeric
newDF$"xright" <- as.numeric(newDF$"xright") # -//-

#> newDF
#      range  type xleft xright
#1   10 - 20 helix    10     20
#2   28 - 30  beta    28     30
#3     3 - 8  turn     3      8
#4 100 - 180 helix   100    180
#5 185 - 190  beta   185    190
#6 200 - 350  turn   200    350

#color for each type
colors. <- c(rgb(0,1,0,1/3), rgb(0,0,1,1/3), rgb(1,0,0,1/3))[as.factor(newDF$type)]

#background plot 
plot(NULL, xlim = c(0, max(newDF[c("xleft", "xright")])), 
                        ylim = c(0,1), yaxt = "n", ann = F)

#legend
legend(x = max(newDF[c("xleft", "xright")]) * 0.5, y = 1.15, xpd = T, ncol = 3, 
         legend = c("beta", "helix", "turn"), 
             fill = c(rgb(0,1,0,1/3), rgb(0,0,1,1/3), rgb(1,0,0,1/3)))

#function that draws rectangles for each range
fun <- function(xl, yb, xr, yt, col.)
{
 rect(xleft = xl, ybottom = yb, xright = xr, ytop = yt, col = col.)
} 

#draw all rectangles
mapply(fun, xl = newDF$xleft, xr = newDF$xright, col. = colors., 
                       MoreArgs = list(yb = 0, yt = 1))
```

The plot is drawn square-like, but you can change its dimensions either by dragging its box or by extracting it in a `jpeg` (or anything) with the wanted dimensions:

[image: rect-like plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help and directions.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the plot with your code. But the last statement gives some error in `colors`

Comment: @aravindramesh: You tried the actual code in my answer or you tried to apply the code in your data? I ran it again and it worked for me. What error is it exactly?

Comment: I was run the code presented in your answer. The error was `Error in mapply(fun, xl = newDF$xleft, xr = newDF$xright, col. = colors.,  : 
  object 'colors.' not found`

Comment: @aravindramesh: I suppose this means that you have not run the line `colors. <- c(rgb(0,1,0,1/3), rgb(0,0,1,1/3), rgb(1,0,0,1/3))[as.factor(newDF$type)]` from the answer.